# how to populate spring.active.profiles values in azure devops build pipelines

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am using profiling in spring boot application and have below files.

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-test.properties
```

To load dev related profiles,in local application I am using below property in `application.properties` file.

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

If I want to activate and use test then I make a change in `application.properties` file as below

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

As I am new to AzureDevOps, want to know how this profile property value can be configured so as it is auto populated in CI/CD pipeline during release. The dev deployment stage should pick up dev code and test stage will pick up test related code.

How to set value for this `spring.profiles.active` property in CI CD pipelines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extension tools you can use in azure ci/cd pipeline to replace the profile property value during release. Eg. [RegEx Find & Replace task](https://github.com/knom/vsts-regex-tasks/). See below steps:

1, Install the RegEx Find & Replace task from the market place.

2, Add RegEx Find & Replace task to the top of your pipeline. And configure it as below in dev stage:

[image]

Above configuration will match the `spring\.profiles\.active=.*` and replace it to `spring.profiles.active=dev` using RegEx in the in application.properties file.

3, In the test stage. Change the replace value to `spring.profiles.active=test`

Comment: Checking this solution. One clarification need. This to be used in Release (CD) pipeline or both CI and CD pipelines ?

Comment: @bee  This can be used in both CI and CD, wherever you need to replace the profile property value.